# Unable to log in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, log

I am unable to log into my  Ubuntu 12.04 machine, username and password prompts reapper again. I can only log in as a guest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login into the system. If your password is correct, you will succeed. Then run

rm .Xauthority .ICEauthority

Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and try to login again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it says incorrect login. Please clarify thanks

Comment: If you entered login and password, not mixing them up, it means that your password is incorrect.

Comment: It is correct, i don't understand what is the issue here. Please help, i do not want to lose valuable date on my laptop! thanks

Comment: If you can't login to system console, it means that login/password are incorrect. I can't guess why it happened. You won't lose your data, because you can always boot from LiveCD and copy the data anywhere you choose.

Comment: user login appears, but the password does not appear once typed, is that normal?

Comment: Yes, it is normal.

Comment: Check for capslock, language, etc.

Comment: i am very sure both log in and password are correct, any other alternatives? its getting frustrating

Comment: But the system is sure they are not correct. There may be many reasons for that. You probably entered some wrong command, etc. As I said, you can boot frome external drive and extract your data.

Comment: Fine, i am new to Ubuntu I'd appreciate if you could help me through the steps of extracting my data rather than wasting time on fixing this issue. Thanks

Comment: Or you can recover the password. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password